# Is there some sort of irregular grid in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

So I did not really know how to phrase this question. I have a picture of a climbing wall with lots of holds. I want the user to be able to touch a hold and it will be added to the current route. The problem is that the holds have different sizes, there is a different number of holds per row etc. I'm new to Xamarin and I heard that using concrete sizes and positions are a bad way to do that. I have no idea which control/s are suited for that task and how to manage such a manual and specific task while also keeping a good alignment for all devices. Here is the picture of the wall so maybe my problem can be easier understood (have to post the link because I do not have enough reputation to post an inline image):

https://i.gyazo.com/a314069f7bf81dd0594294d03a17d9d8.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest using SkiaSharp

Comment: I would create a map of positions/bounding boxes relative to the original size of the image and use that to determine which hold has been touched. SkiaSharp could be a good fit for this problem. You could use something like [SkiaScene](https://github.com/OndrejKunc/SkiaScene) to allow for zooming/panning the image. Then you could draw on top of the image, which holds have been added to the route.